# A body falls through a medium

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'm hating these variable resistance questions.

A body of mass $m$ falls from rest in a medium that produces a resistance of magnitude $m\cdot k \cdot v$. where $k$ is a constant, where the speed of the particle is $v$. Show that when the body has reached a speed $V$ it will have fallen for a time

$$\frac{1}{k} \ln \left(\frac{g}{g-k\cdot V}\right) \; .$$

Help much appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? You should at least be able to get the differential equation(s) which need(s) solving.

Comment: The formula for the time should include big V for the "final" speed. Not small v.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this at [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the force on the particle due to gravity is $mg,$ where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, so the net downward force on the particle is $m(g-kv).$ So its acceleration is
$g-kv.$ So you need to solve $dv/dt = g-kv$ given the initial conditions. That is

$$\int_0^V \frac{ \text{d}v}{g-kv} = \int_0^T \text{d}t.$$

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is my noob way of solving this  (I only learned this less than a year ago but I have forgotten everything and semester starts in a few weeks and I'll probably be required to do this stuff EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP),

The forces on the "body" are the resistance and its weight (gravity) as far as I can tell from your description

So 
$$ \vec{F}_{net} = m\mathbf{a} =mg-mk\mathbf{v} $$

which can be simplified to

$$  \mathbf{a} = g-k\mathbf{v}  $$

which can be written in a slightly different form as because acceleration is derivative of velocity

$$  v'(t)+k v(t)=g  $$

This looks type of equation looks familiar to me and can be solved as it is a ["linear first order differential equation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation)

Now here is where I may start to make errors so please forgive me

First we multiple everything an "integrating factor" equal to $e^{\int f(t)\,dt}$ where $f(t)=k,$ to make it all work so

$$e^{\int f(t)\,dt}=e^{\int k\,dt}=e^{kt}$$

We don't need a "plus C" (I'm not entirely clear on this but I don't think it makes a difference to anything in the long run, SOMEONE PLEASE CONFIRM)

So when we multiply everything by $e^{kt} $

$$  v'(t)e^{kt}+k v(t)e^{kt}=ge^{kt} $$

which is "equivalent" to this (look at the product rule)

$$  (v(t)e^{kt})'=ge^{kt} $$

Now if we integrate both sides

$$  v(t)e^{kt}={\int ge^{kt}\,dt}$$

$$  v(t)e^{kt}=\frac{ge^{kt}}{k}+C$$

$$  v(t)=\frac{C}{e^{kt}}+\frac{g}{k}$$

To get rid of the C, you said it starts from rest so $v(0)=0$

$$  v(0)=0=\frac{C}{e^{k0}}+\frac{g}{k} = \frac{C}{1}+\frac{g}{k}$$
$$ 0= C+\frac{g}{k}$$
$$ C=-\frac{g}{k}$$

So

$$  v(t)=\frac{-\frac{g}{k}}{e^{kt}}+\frac{g}{k}$$

and I would simplify this to

$$  v(t)=g\frac{1-e^{-kt}}{k}$$

Now Wolfram Alpha would have done [this for you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=v%27%28t%29%2Bk+v%28t%29%3Dg)

Now to the second part of your question when v(t)=V what is t?

$$  v(t)=V=g\frac{1-e^{-kt}}{k}$$

$$  \frac{kV}{g}={1-e^{-kt}}$$

$$  e^{-kt}=1-\frac{kV}{g}$$

$$  e^{-kt}=\frac{g-kV}{g}$$

$$  e^{kt}=\frac{g}{g-kV}$$

$$  kt=\log_e {\frac{g}{g-kV}}$$

$$  t=\frac{1}{k}\log_e ({\frac{g}{g-kV}})$$

Wolfram Alpha would do this too but is down for me now

I hope this is correct

Comment: I feel dumb after seeing [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22312/a-body-falls-through-a-medium/22343#22343) 

TOTAL BRAIN FADE